# Controlling of input size in irvine32 of assembly?

Tags: assembly, input, size, masm, irvine32

How can I limit the size of input when I was taking player name from user? I am using like that:

```
player1 byte 36 dup(' '),0
```

but when the player entered more than 36 characters, computer is giving alert sound and remain part is writing to part of player2 name.

Comment: Please provide more information about your target environment.  How are you obtaining the input?

Comment: i am writin a memory game. at the beginning of game i am taking user name from users and there is no limit for their name size.For example, Player1 can write name as like "stackoverflow" or "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" because of that i have to control the size of player's name. Firstly, i used  player1 byte 36 dup(' '),0 but it is taking only 36 character of input. and system is giving alert sound which is like mov al,7 call writechar.

Comment: Yes, but on what system?  Under what operating system?  Using what method (system call, library function, software IRQ, etc) to obtain user input?  We can't help you without that - though one obvious method is to switch to a character-by-character input method, keep count, and refuse/error if the count exceeds a maximum.

Comment: here system is called computer and under windowds operating system.in data part there is only  player1 byte 36 dup(' '),0 and in code segment i am taking name like mwrite "Enter first player's name: "
mov edx, offset player1
mov ecx, lengthof player1-1
call readstring

Answer (score 0):

From: http://lcs.syr.edu/faculty/pease/handouts/CSE%20281/Irvine%20Programming%20Examples/Lib32/Irvine32_Library/Irvine32.asm

```
;--------------------------------------------------------
ReadString PROC
    LOCAL bufSize:DWORD, saveFlags:DWORD, junk:DWORD
;
; Reads a string from the keyboard and places the characters
; in a buffer.
; Receives: EDX offset of the input buffer
;           ECX = maximum characters to input (including terminal null)
; Returns:  EAX = size of the input string.
; Comments: Stops when Enter key (0Dh,0Ah) is pressed. If the user
; types more characters than (ECX-1), the excess characters
; are ignored.
; Written by Kip Irvine and Gerald Cahill
;
; Last update: 11/19/92, 03/20/2003
;--------------------------------------------------------`
```

So the answer is that you should set ECX to the maximum number of characters you are able to safely accept into your buffer, inclusive of the null.  Perhaps you are not correctly setting that value - you could try manually making it artificially short such as 10 characters and verifying that it has an effect.

Comment: thank you for advices Chris but maximum size is unknown.If i write 10 for maximum character, my teacher will try 11 character. Is there any advice for it?

Comment: The maximum size is the size of the buffer you are providing to the function.  Anything larger would be unsafe for the program.  If that is insufficient for the project requirement you will have to increase the size of the buffer first.